# Learn monogame or xna

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

Firstly, I have never worked in XNA. I was learning C# recently but I don't why I liked it over other languages learnt so far. Then I stepped over to Monogame and tried learning it. It is also fun. I even came to know that Monogame is a great choice for XNA developers as XNA is being deprecated. I don't know if I should continue learning Monogame or not as I don't know anything about XNA although I know that most of the things in Monogame are same. So shall I continue with Monogame or first learn XNA and then move on to Monogame or should I leave both and look for something else? And does Monogame have something to do with Xamarin?

Also XNA is not supported on WIndows 8 and Windows Phone 8. So will there be updates in XNA for these platforms or earlier platforms like Windows Phone 7, Xbox etc.?

Comment: AFAIK MonoGame uses Mono for Android for deployment in Android devices - and that is a non-free framework sold by Xamarin. You'll be able to develop and test in your PC, using an emulator, but in order to deploy your builds to your phones/tablets/Ouya, you'll need a license. I think the cheapest license for it is around 800 USD. Well worth it if you're going to use it professionally. But even if you don't wanna pay, do learn it (it's pretty fun). I am doing so - and I'll buy that license when I have a game I can sell on Google Play.

Comment: Wont DirectX require C++? I know C++ (little more than beginner) but right now I want to stick with C#.

Comment: "Go for DirectX" is really bad advice without some context. Firstly, it's much harder to learn and secondly it's not cross platform. Stick with C# for now.

Answer (score 3):

Monogame and XNA have a great deal in common, because Monogame is essentially an open source version of XNA.

- As you hinted, you can use [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) to make your games cross-platform quite easily. This means you can reuse loads of your code and have iOS and Android versions of your game. This is a great advantage of Monogame if that's what you want to do.
- With XNA there are quite a few libraries built for it which might make building your game easier e.g. [Mercury paricle effects engine](http://mpe.codeplex.com/)

In my opinion, it might be easier to get started with XNA. There are loads of great resources out there to get you off the ground. The last thing you want to be doing first off is faffing around with dlls trying to get the damn thing to compile.

Good luck!

Comment: So I should leave Monogame and learn XNA first?

Comment: I'd say you will probably have a better time doing that. Anything you've learned in Monogame will be transferable to XNA. If and when your totally awesome at XNA and decide you want to create a cross-platform game, that's probably the time to pickup Monogame again.